# Java JOptionPane returning method from another class

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a method in a class that creates a summary or report of information for all of the nurses of a system. The method shows all of the trainee nurses that belong to nurses. I have created another class that creates a `JFrame` and `JOptionPane` for the user to input information. I am trying to make the `JOptionPane` return the summary for just one particular nurse and the trainee nurses that they are in charge of, once the name is inputted into the `JOptionPane`. I can't provide any code but any help would be great

Comment: Do you mean a JOptionPane, or is JOptionPanel a class of your own?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this without code, or at least a better description of what is going wrong. You've stated your problem, but not what you expect to happen vs. what is actually happening, a screenshot, or supporting code. If this is a proprietary application, then you can probably post code so long as any sensitive information is removed. If that's not feasible, then you'd likely be better off talking to another programmer who does have access to the code, and can have a live conversation with you.

Comment: You basically want an action that is performed on a `JOptionPane` or `JOptionPanel` to invoke a method in another class?

Comment: Because you can't provide any existing code, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is even more useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a JOptionPane, the application waits for the user to supply an input, given that it is a modal dialog - it sounds as if you want to use the showInputDialog method in order to get back the requested nurse - then your application could carry on once the input was supplied and pass that information (however a 'nurse' is represented for you) to this other class to perform whatever actions you need done.